# using a lua file to require other lua files?

Tags: lua, require

can someone tell me if its possible in lua to do something like this?
where it uses a module file to include other module files using a single lua header?

```
--main.lua
require "std"
local test = WIDGETS[0]

--std.lua
require "std.constants" -- this is the problem its local to this file only
require "std.functions" -- this is the problem its local to this file only

-std.constants.lua
WIDGETS = 
{
   NONE,
   PANEL,
   BUTTON
}
```

I need to do something like this so I don't have to type std.constants.WIDGET[whatever]

Answer (score 1):

You could add the line `local WIDGETS = std.constants.WIDGETS` after your `require "std"`. Then, all functions in that file can reference `WIDGETS` without polluting the global namespace:

```
-- main.lua
require "std"
local WIDGETS = std.constants.WIDGETS

local test = WIDGETS[0]
...
```

You would only have to do this once per file.

Comment: thats the thing though I want it to put it in the global namespace thats why I was doing it that way. I don't want to have to require it and assign all of the functions and constants to a variable for every file, there could be hundreds of functions and constants